# Adjust ImageBackground to fullscreen

Tags: ios, react-native, imagebackground

I have given an ImageBackground component and I want it to take the whole screen but it appears to have small paddings even if I resize twice or more the image. Where does it comes from ?

[image]

```
Here is the code of the component

import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Button, ImageBackground, StyleSheet } from "react- 
native";

export class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

static navigationOptions = {
  //To hide the NavigationBar from current Screen
  header: null
};

render() {
  return (
     <ImageBackground source={require('../imgs/bgx.png')} style={ 
       styles.container }>
     </ImageBackground>
  );
}


}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    resizeMode: 'stretch'
  }
});
```

Comment: bro, that picture is huge......

Comment: Make sure your original picture fits the aspect ratio of the iOS device and then make extra sure it is 24 BPP (opaque) meaning no alpha channel in the image.

Comment: It seems that is the reason ! I've tried with another image and it fits perfectly ! thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your source image does *not* have any transparency around.

Set `width: '100%'` and `height: '100%'` to the `ImageBackground` component. Does it change anything?

Comment: @HubertSolecki have you tried MoDJ's suggestion about aspect ratio under your post as a comment?

Comment: Yep, was that ;) Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Add `width='100%'` and `height='100%'`